# WordPress Theme Only Broken In Chrome

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome

I seem to be having a really strange issue that only happens in chrome.

My custom theme that i'm using (Simplify. No Support for it anymore...) works great in All browsers except chrome.
The feature boxes and header are very messed up and i'm not sure why it is like that.

I went over to chrome support and they told me to come here....

[My Theme in FireFox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxzE9.jpg)
[My Theme in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlxLH.jpg)

My style.css

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td{border:0;font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;font-style:inherit;font-weight:inherit;margin:0;outline:0;padding:0;vertical-align:baseline;}
:focus{outline:0;}
body{line-height:1;}
ol,
ul{list-style:none;}
table{border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:0;}
caption, th, td{font-weight:normal;text-align:left;}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after{content:"";}
blockquote,
q{quotes:"" "";}
a img{border:0;}
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section{display:block;}
.alignnone{margin:5px 20px 20px 0;}
.aligncenter,
div.aligncenter{display:block;margin:5px auto 5px auto;}
.alignright{float:right;margin:5px 0 20px 20px;}
.alignleft{float:left;margin:5px 20px 20px 0;}
.aligncenter{display:block;margin:5px auto 5px auto;}
a img.alignright{float:right;margin:5px 0 20px 20px;}
a img.alignnone{margin:5px 20px 20px 0;}
a img.alignleft{float:left;margin:5px 20px 20px 0;}
a img.aligncenter{display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}
.wp-caption{background:#fff;border:1px solid #f0f0f0;max-width:96%;padding:5px 3px 10px;text-align:center;}
.wp-caption.alignnone{margin:5px 20px 20px 0;}
.wp-caption.alignleft{margin:5px 20px 20px 0;}
.wp-caption.alignright{margin:5px 0 20px 20px;}
.wp-caption img{border:0 none;height:auto;margin:0;max-width:98.5%;padding:0;width:auto;}
.wp-caption p.wp-caption-text{font-size:11px;line-height:17px;margin:0;padding:0 4px 5px;}
body{color:#6a6969;font-family:'Anaheim', sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:1.15;min-width:950px;word-wrap:break-word;}
div, p, a, li, img{transition:all 2s;-moz-transition:all 2s;-o-transition:all 2s;-webkit-transition:all 2s;}
#slide div, #slide p, #slide a, #slide li, #slide img{transition:none;-moz-transition:none;-o-transition:none;-webkit-transition:none;}
img{max-width:100%;border:0 none;}
#container{width:930px;margin:40px auto;}
#header{height:90px;background:url("images/header.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #333333;}
#header-bottom{background:url("images/header-bottom.png") no-repeat scroll center top #3c4143;height:500px;margin:-7px 0 -610px;}
img.site-logo, .site-title {max-width:250px;max-height:70px;padding:5px 0;float:left;}
.site-title { padding: 20px 0; font-size: 35px; text-transform: uppercase; max-width: 300px; }
#header-content{width:930px;margin:auto;}
.site-title-hidden{display:none;}
#content{float:left;width:70%;}
#content-full{width:930px;}
.content-ver-sep{background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCCCCC;border-bottom:1px solid #FFFFFF;clear:both;height:1px;}
.lsep{background:url("images/lsep.png") no-repeat scroll top center #CCCCCC;clear:both;height:20px;margin:10px auto;}
#right-sidebar{float:right;width:25%;}
#footer{background:url("images/footer.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #26292B;border-bottom:50px solid #111111;clear:both;padding:0px;min-width:930px; border-top: 10px solid #000000;}
.versep{background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #111111;border-bottom:1px solid #222222;border-top:80px solid #222222;height:2px;}
#footer-content{width:930px;margin:0 auto;}
#social{display:table;height:50px;margin:-70px auto 30px;padding:0 10px 10px;}

.youtube-link,
.gplus-link,
.picassa-link,
.li-link,
.feed-link{float:left;height:50px;width:50px;}
.youtube-link{background:url("images/youtubeicon.png") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;margin:0 20px;}
.youtube-link:hover{background:url("images/youtubeicon.png") no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent;}
.gplus-link{background:url("images/gplusicon.png") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;margin:0 20px;}
.gplus-link:hover{background:url("images/gplusicon.png") no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent;}
.picassa-link{background:url("images/picassaicon.png") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;margin:0 20px;}
.picassa-link:hover{background:url("images/picassaicon.png") no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent;}
.li-link{background:url("images/liicon.png") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;margin:0 40px 0 20px;}
.li-link:hover{background:url("images/liicon.png") no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent;}
.feed-link{background:url("images/feedicon.png") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;}
.feed-link:hover{background:url("images/feedicon.png") no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent;}
#footer-sidebar{overflow:hidden;padding-top:20px;}
#creditline{color:#8A96A0;font-size:13px;margin-bottom:-40px;text-align:center;padding: 5px;}
#creditline a{font-weight:bold;}
#simplify-main-menu{color:#EEEEEE;float:right;line-height:1;max-width:650px;}
#simplify-main-menu ul{list-style:none outside none;}
#simplify-main-menu li{float:left;position:relative;margin:0 5px;}
#simplify-main-menu a{color:#AAAAAA;display:block;font-size:13px;min-width:40px;padding: 25px 10px 29px;position:relative;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;border-bottom:5px solid transparent;}
#simplify-main-menu a:hover,
#simplify-main-menu .current-menu-item > a,
#simplify-main-menu .current-menu-ancestor > a,
#simplify-main-menu .current_page_item > a,
#simplify-main-menu .current_page_ancestor > a{color:#45a9f6;border-bottom:5px solid #45a9f6;}
#simplify-main-menu li ul{float:left;position:relative;margin:0;}
#simplify-main-menu ul ul,
.sub-menu, .sub-menu ul ul{display:none;float:left;left:0;position:absolute;border-bottom:5px solid #000000;border-top:5px solid #000000;border-radius:5px;background:#F2F2F2;background:rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.95);padding:5px;box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px #000000;z-index:10000;}
#simplify-main-menu ul li ul li{margin:0;}
#simplify-main-menu ul ul ul{left:100%;top:0;z-index:999;}
#simplify-main-menu ul ul a{border-bottom:1px solid #BFBFBF;border-top:1px solid #FFFFFF;color:#242424;padding:9px 15px;width:140px;text-align:left;text-transform:none;}
#simplify-main-menu ul ul a:hover,
#simplify-main-menu ul ul .current-menu-item > a,
#simplify-main-menu ul ul .current-menu-ancestor > a,
#simplify-main-menu ul ul .current_page_item > a,
#simplify-main-menu ul ul .current_page_ancestor > a{background:#555555;color:#EEEEEE;border-bottom:1px solid #BFBFBF;}
#simplify-main-menu ul li:hover > ul{display:block;}
.widget{display:block;word-wrap:break-word;}
#right-sidebar .widget{background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCCCCC;margin-bottom:20px;padding:15px;}
#right-sidebar .widget h3{color:#555555;padding-bottom:5px;text-transform:uppercase;}
#right-sidebar .widget,
#right-sidebar .widget li,
#right-sidebar .widget a,
#right-sidebar .widget a:hover{color:#333333;text-decoration:none;}
#right-sidebar .widget ul{border-bottom:1px solid #EEEEEE;border-top:1px solid #999999;margin:0;}
#right-sidebar .widget li{background:url("images/listicon.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 8px transparent;border-bottom:1px solid #999999;border-top:1px solid #EEEEEE;list-style:none outside none;padding:5px 0 5px 17px;}
#footer-sidebar .widget{margin-bottom:30px;}
#footer-widget{float:left;}
#footer-sidebar .widgets{margin-left:6%;float:left;}
#footer-sidebar #footer-widget{width:20.5%;}
#footer-sidebar .widget h3{color:#EEEEEE;text-transform:uppercase;}
#footer-sidebar .widget,
#footer-sidebar .widget li,
#footer-sidebar .widget a,
#footer-sidebar .widget a:hover{color:#BAB4B4;text-decoration:none;}
#footer-sidebar .widget ul{margin:0;}
#footer-sidebar .widget li{background:url("images/listicon.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 8px transparent;list-style:none outside none;padding:5px 0 5px 17px;}
#right-sidebar input#s,
#footer-sidebar input#s{width:60%;min-width:100px;}
#right-sidebar form#searchform input[type="submit"],
#footer-sidebar form#searchform input[type="submit"]{padding:8px 7px;}
.textwedget{width:100%;}
h1, h2, h2 a, h2 a:visited, h3, h4, h5, h6{font-family:'Poiret One', cursive, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;line-height:1.25;margin:0 0 10px;}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{clear:both;}
hr{background-color:#ccc;border:0;height:1px;margin-bottom:10px;}
ul, ol{margin:0 0 10px 25px;}
ul{list-style:square outside none;}
ol{list-style:decimal outside none;}
dl{margin:0 20px;}
dt{font-weight:bold;}
dd{margin-bottom:10px;}
strong{font-weight:bold;}
cite, em, i{font-style:italic;}
blockquote cite,
blockquote em,
blockquote i{font-style:normal;}
pre{background:#FFFFFF;border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;color:#222222;line-height:18px;margin-bottom:18px;overflow:auto;padding:1.5em;}
abbr,
acronym{border-bottom:1px dotted #666;cursor:help;}
sup,
sub{height:0;line-height:1;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:70%;}
sup{bottom:1ex;}
sub{top:.5ex;}
address{background:#EEEEEE;border:2px solid #DDDDDD;border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;font-weight:bold;margin-bottom:15px;max-width:250px;padding:5px 10px;text-align:right;}
embed{max-width:100%;}
#container .gallery{margin:0 auto 1.625em;}
#container .gallery a img{border:none;}
#container .gallery .attachment-thumbnail{float:none;margin:5px auto;}
img#wpstats{display:block;margin:0 auto 1.625em;}
#container .gallery-columns-1 .gallery-item{width:80%;}
#container .gallery-columns-2 .gallery-item{width:40%;}
#container .gallery-columns-3 .gallery-item{width:27%;}
#container .gallery-columns-4 .gallery-item{width:19%;}
#container .gallery-columns-4 .gallery-item img{width:100%;height:auto;}
h1{font-size:30px;}
h2{font-size:23px;}
h3{font-size:20px;}
h4{font-size:17px;}
h5{font-size:15px;}
h6{font-size:13px;}
p{margin-bottom:15px;}
a{color:#0387BF;text-decoration:none;}
b, strong{font-weight:bold;}
displaynone{display:none;}
.clear{clear:both;}
table{background-color:#EEEEEE;border:1px solid #FFFFFF;border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px;padding:5px;-moz-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;min-width:200px;color:#333333;}
td{padding:5px 7px;vertical-align:top;}
#wp-calendar td{padding:0px 7px;}
th{font-weight:bold;line-height:1;padding:5px 7px;text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);background:#CCC;}
caption{color:#555555;}
table#wp-calendar{width:100%;}
input[type="text"],
textarea, input#s,
input[type="password"]{background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #EDEDED;border-radius:5px;font-size:14px;padding:10px 7px;width:98%;border-top:1px solid #999999;border-left:1px solid #999999;border-right:1px solid #FFFFFF;border-bottom:1px solid #FFFFFF;}
input[type="password"]{width:200px;}
input[type="text"]:focus,
textarea:focus,
input#s:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus{background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #F7F7F7;}
button,
input[type="reset"],
input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"]{-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #0eb3cc;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #0eb3cc;box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 0px #555555;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #11a5db), color-stop(1, #085d96));background:-moz-linear-gradient(center top, #11a5db 5%, #085d96 100%);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#11a5db', endColorstr='#085d96');background-color:#11a5db;-moz-border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;border-radius:5px;border:1px solid #0785b3;display:inline-block;color:#f7f7f7;font-family:arial;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;padding:5px 15px 6px;text-decoration:none;text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #555555;min-height:35px;text-transform:uppercase;cursor:pointer;margin:5px 0;}
button:hover,
input[type="reset"]:hover,
input[type="button"]:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover{background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #085d96), color-stop(1, #11a5db));background:-moz-linear-gradient(center top, #085d96 5%, #11a5db 100%);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#085d96', endColorstr='#11a5db');background-color:#085d96;}
button:active,
input[type="reset"]:active,
input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="submit"]:active{position:relative;top:1px;}
input#s{width:70%;min-width:235px;}
.post.sticky,
.sticky{background:url("images/sticky.png") no-repeat scroll right top #F2F2F2;margin-bottom:30px;padding:15px;}
.gallery-caption{clear:both;width:95%;}
.bypostauthor{}
#container,
#content,
#content-full{font-size:14px;text-align:justify;}
#content img,
#content-full img{height:auto;max-width:100%;vertical-align:middle;}
#content img.wp-smiley,
#content-full img.wp-smiley{border:none;box-shadow:none;}
#heading{color:#CCCCCC;font-size:35px;margin: 40px auto;text-align:center;width:700px;font-weight:100;}
.heading-desc{color:#AAAAAA;font-size:14px;margin:-40px auto 10px;text-align:center;width:700px;}
#slide-container{width:930px;height:383px;background:url("images/sliderbottom.png") no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent;margin:30px 0;}
#slide{width:930px;height:350px;overflow:hidden;}
#slide-container a, #slide{transition:none;-moz-transition:none;-o-transition:none;-webkit-transition:none;}
#slide img{width:930px;height:350px;overflow:hidden;}
#ft-buttons-slide{text-align:left;margin:-30px 30px 0;width:870px; font-size: 0px; position: absolute; position: absolute;}
.ft-button-slide { background: transparent; border-radius: 50%; margin: 0 5px; border: 2px solid #FFFFFF; border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5); width: 1px; height: 1px; display: inline-block;  }
.ft-button-slide-active { background: #FFFFFF; background: rgba(255,255,255,.7); }

#ft-title-slide{position:absolute;bottom:0pt;margin-left:400px;z-index:1000;opacity:1;width:500px;font-size:15px;}
#ft-title-slide blockquote{background:#EEEEEE;background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.70);color:#333333;font-size:17px;text-align:right;box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 #999999;border-left:10px solid #999999;border-right:10px solid #999999;}
#ft-title-slide blockquote h3{margin:0;}
#ft-title-slide blockquote:before{content:'';margin-right:0;}
#ft-title-slide blockquote:after{content:'';margin-left:0;}
#featured-boxs{padding:0;display:inline-block;text-align:left;}
.featured-box{width:210px;margin-left:30px;}
.featured-box h3{font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-weight:100;font-size:15px;color:#555555;}
#featured-boxs h2{font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-weight:100;font-size:19px;color:#555555;}
.featured-box-first{padding:20px 0;width:210px;margin:0;}
#featured-boxs img.box-image{border:3px solid #EEEEEE;width:202px;height:100px;}
#featured-boxs img.box-image:hover{box-shadow:0 0 11px 0px #555555;}
#featured-boxs img.box-icon{width:50px;height:50px;}
h3.featured-box2{width:140px;float:right;}
.featured-box,
.featured-box-first{display:inline;float:left;}
#customers-comment{font-size:17px;font-weight:bold;margin-top:20px;line-height:2;}
blockquote, q {background:#DDDDDD;background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);border-left:10px solid #ccc;margin:20px 10px;padding:10px;quotes:quotes:'<<' '>>';border-right:10px solid #ccc;}
blockquote:before, q:before {color:#ccc;content:'\201C';font-size:4em;line-height:.1em;margin-right:.20em;vertical-align:-.4em;}
blockquote:after, q:after {color:#ccc;content:'\201D';font-size:4em;line-height:.1em;margin-left:.20em;vertical-align:-.4em;}
blockquote p, q p {display:inline;}
#container .attachment-thumbnail{border:1px solid #AAAAAA;border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px;margin:0px 15px 10px 0;padding:3px;float:left;}
#container .gallery .attachment-thumbnail{float:none;margin:5px auto;}
h1.page-title,
h1.arc-post-title{font-size:35px;text-shadow:-1px -1px 3px #FFFFFF;text-transform:uppercase;text-align:left;color:#45a9f6;}
h2.post-title,
h2.comments,
h3#reply-title,
h2.post-title-color{font-size:25px;margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:10px;text-align:left;text-shadow:-1px -1px 3px #FFFFFF;text-transform:uppercase;}
.entrytext{padding:10px 0;}
h2.post-title a,
h2.post-title a:hover,
h2.comments a,
h2.post-title-color{color:#45a9f6;}
h3.arc-src{text-transform:uppercase;color:#F60;font-size:20px;}
h3 span{color:#777777;}
.post,
.hentry,
.no-results{margin-bottom:20px;}
.read-more{background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;border:1px solid #C5C7C8;border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;box-shadow:0 0 3px 0 #C5C7C8;display:table;padding:5px 10px;margin-top:10px;}
.read-more a{color:#555555;}
.postmetadata{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;text-shadow:0 0 1px #FFFFFF;}
p.postmetadata{margin:0;}
.postmetadata a{color:#0387BF;}
.postmetadataw{letter-spacing:3px;font-weight:bold;}
.up-bottom-border{background:url("images/bottom.png") no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent;display:inline-block;margin-bottom:10px;padding:5px 0 25px 0;width:100%;border-top:1px solid #EEEEEE;}
.page-link{font-weight:bold;}
.page-link a{background:#AAAAAA;padding:0 5px;color:#FFFFFF;}
.floatleft{float:left;width:45%;text-align:left;}
.floatright{float:right;width:45%;text-align:right;}
#page-nav .alignright{text-align:right;}
#page-nav .alignleft{text-align:left;}
#page-nav a{border-width:1px;font-size:17px;font-weight:bold;padding:10px;}
#commentsbox .commentlist{margin:0;}
#commentsbox .watermark{color:rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.7);font-family:'Oswald',arial,serif;font-size:17px;text-align:center;text-shadow:none;text-transform:uppercase;}
#commentsbox .comment-author cite,
#commentsbox .comment-author cite a{color:#1072BC;letter-spacing:3px;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;}
#commentsbox img.avatar{left:0;position:absolute;ttop:7px;}
#commentsbox ul.children{padding:0;}
.comment-body{padding:0 0 10px;}
#commentsbox .commentlist li.comment{border-top:1px solid #EEEEEE;line-height:19px;margin:0 0 24px;padding:5px 0 0 50px;position:relative;}
#comments .comment-body p:last-child{margin-bottom:6px;}
#commentsbox .comment-meta,
#commentsbox .comment-meta a:link,
#commentsbox .comment-meta a:visited{color:#AAAAAA;font-size:12px;padding-bottom:10px;text-shadow:none;}
#commentsbox .commentlist .children li{border-top:2px solid #FFFFFF;list-style:none outside none;margin:0 0 0 -25px;}
#commentsbox .commentlist li:last-child{border-bottom:medium none;ist-style:none outside none;}
#comment-form{max-width:550px;}
#respond .required{color:#ff4b33;font-weight:bold;position:absolute;}
#commentsbox ol.commentlist, #commentsbox li.commentlist{padding:0;list-style:none;}
#comments-list #respond{margin:0 0 18px 0;}
#comments-list ul #respond{margin:0;}
#cancel-comment-reply-link{font-weight:normal;line-height:18px;}
#respond input{margin:0 0 9px;}
#respond textarea{width:98%;}
#respond .form-allowed-tags{font-size:13px;line-height:18px;}
#respond .form-allowed-tags code{font-size:11px;}
#respond .form-submit{margin:12px 0;}
#respond .form-submit input{font-size:14px;width:auto;}
h2#client-text.post-title{color:#888A8A;opacity:0.7;padding:10px 0;text-align:center;}
#client{display:table;display:block\9;margin:20px auto;}
#client img{margin:0 13px;max-height:100px;vertical-align:middle;width:100px;}
#f-post-page { margin: 10px auto; width: 100%; font-size: 15px; cursor: pointer; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; } 
#f-post-page-container { display: none; }
/* Text meant only for screen readers. */
.screen-reader-text { clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); position: absolute !important; height: 1px; width: 1px; overflow: hidden; }
.screen-reader-text:focus { background-color: #f1f1f1; border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); clip: auto !important; color: #21759b;  display: block; font-size: 14px; font-size: 0.875rem; font-weight: bold; height: auto; left: 5px; line-height: normal; padding: 15px 23px 14px;  text-decoration: none; top: 5px; width: auto; z-index: 100000; /* Above WP toolbar. */ }


/* =Media Print
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media print {

h1 { page-break-before:always; }
h1,  h2,  h3,  h4,  h5,  h6 { page-break-after:avoid; }
ul,  ol,  dl { page-break-before:avoid; }
}
```

HTML for the slide show and heading text

```html
get_header(); ?>
<div id="header-bottom"> </div>
<div id="container">
<h1 id="heading"><?php echo esc_textarea(simplify_get_option('heading-text', __('Welcome to the World of Creativity!','simplify'))); ?></h1>
<p class="heading-desc"><?php echo esc_textarea(simplify_get_option('heading-des', __('WordPress is web software you can use to create a beautiful website or blog. We like to say that WordPress is both free and priceless at the same time.','simplify'))); ?></p>

<div id="slide-container">
<div id="slide">
<img src="<?php echo esc_url(simplify_get_option('banner-image', get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/slide-image/slide-image1.jpg')); ?>" />
<?php if ( esc_url(simplify_get_option('slide-image', get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/slide-image/slide-image2.jpg')) != '' ) : ?>
<img src="<?php echo esc_url(simplify_get_option('slide-image', get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/slide-image/slide-image2.jpg')); ?>"  />
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( esc_url(simplify_get_option('extra-image', get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/slide-image/slide-image3.jpg')) != '' ) : ?>
<img src="<?php echo esc_url(simplify_get_option('extra-image', get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/slide-image/slide-image3.jpg')); ?>"  />
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div> <!-- slide-container -->


<?php get_template_part( 'featured-box' ); ?>

<br /><br /><div class="clear"></div><div class="content-ver-sep"></div><br />

<?php if (esc_html(simplify_get_option('fpost', '0')) != '1'):  get_template_part( 'front-page-blog' ); endif;?> 

<?php if ( esc_textarea(simplify_get_option('bottom-quotation', __('All the developers of D5 Creation have come from the disadvantaged part or group of the society. All have established themselves after a long and hard struggle in their life ----- D5 Creation Team','simplify'))) != '' ) : ?>

<div id="customers-comment">
<blockquote><?php echo esc_textarea(simplify_get_option('bottom-quotation', __('All the developers of D5 Creation have come from the disadvantaged part or group of the society. All have established themselves after a long and hard struggle in their life ----- D5 Creation Team','simplify'))); ?></blockquote>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

HTML for the feature boxes (i.e Quality Hosting, Other Game servers):

```html
<div id="featured-boxs">

<span class="featured-box-first"><h2><?php echo esc_textarea(simplify_get_option('featuredr-title', __('Recent Works','simplify'))); ?></h2><div class="content-ver-sep"></div><br /><p><?php echo esc_textarea(simplify_get_option('featuredr-description',  __('The Color changing options of Simplify will give the WordPress Driven Site an attractive look.','simplify'))); ?></p></span>
<?php 
foreach (range(1, 3) as $fboxn) { ?>
<span class="featured-box"> 
<img class="box-image" src="<?php echo esc_url(simplify_get_option('featured-image' . $fboxn, get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/featured-image' . $fboxn . '.jpg')) ?>"/>
<h3><?php echo esc_textarea(simplify_get_option('featured-title' . $fboxn,  __('Simplify Theme for Small Business','simplify'))); ?></h3>
<div class="content-ver-sep"></div><br />
<p><?php echo esc_textarea(simplify_get_option('featured-description' . $fboxn ,  __('The Color changing options of Simplify will give the WordPress Driven Site an attractive look. Simplify is super elegant and Professional Responsive Theme which will create the business widely expressed.','simplify'))); ?></p>
</span>

<?php }  


if ( esc_html(simplify_get_option('srfbox', '1')) == '1' ): echo '<div class="clear"></div><br /><div class="lsep"></div><br /><br />'; ?>
<br /><span class="featured-box-first"><h2><?php echo esc_textarea(simplify_get_option('featuredr2-title', __('Our Services','simplify'))); ?></h2><div class="content-ver-sep"></div><br /><p><?php echo esc_textarea(simplify_get_option('featuredr2-description', __('Simplify is super elegant and Professional Responsive Theme which will create the business widely expressed.','simplify'))); ?></p></span>
<?php  foreach (range(1, 3) as $fboxn2) { ?>
<span class="featured-box"> 
<img class="box-icon" src="<?php echo esc_url(simplify_get_option('featured-image2' . $fboxn2, get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/featured-image' . $fboxn2 . '.png')) ?>"/>
<h3 class="featured-box2"><?php echo esc_textarea(simplify_get_option('featured-title2' . $fboxn2, __('Simplify Theme for Business','simplify'))); ?></h3>

<div class="clear"> </div>
<p><?php echo esc_textarea(simplify_get_option('featured-description2' . $fboxn2 , __('Simplify is super elegant and Professional Responsive Theme which will create the business widely expressed. The Color changing options of Simplify will give the WordPress Driven Site an attractive look.','simplify'))); ?></p>

</span>

<?php }  ; endif; ?>



</div>
```

Comment: Looks like an `overflow` issue...but we can't help you without your relevant HTML and CSS (not all of it).

Comment: Which files would you need?

Comment: No files...only the relevant HTML and CSS lines.

Comment: Oh so the html code of the things that are broken?

Comment: Yes, we need a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to help.

Comment: Updated the post with the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the issue.

It's a very "cheaty" way out but it works

`@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  #header-bottom{background:url("images/header-bottom.png") no-repeat scroll center top #3c4143;height:500px;margin:-7px 0 -540px;}
  #slide-container{width:930px;height:383px;background:url("images/sliderbottom.png") no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent;margin:40px 0;}
}`